# Transforming a jQuery plugin to support multiple instances

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

Here is a fictional version of my jQuery plugin, but the structure is exactly the same:

```
(function ($)
{
    var initialized = false;
    var element;
    var counter = 0;

    $.fn.myPlugin= function(action)
    {
        if (action === "increase")
        {
            increase(arguments[1]);
        }
        else if (!initialized)
        {
            settings = $.extend({
                ...
            }, action);

            initialized = true;
            element = $(this);

            return this;
        }
        else
        {
            console.error("Unknown function call.");
            return;
        }
    };

    var increase = function(amount)
    {
        counter += amount;
        element.text(counter);
    };
}(jQuery));
```

With this code I am able to initialize my plugin like this:

```
$("#element").myPlugin(options);
```

And I can call the method increase like this:

```
$("#element").myPlugin("increase", 5);
```

However, I am not able to initialize my plugin on multiple elements on one page, because of the variables initilized, element and counter.
How do I modify this code in such a way that I can use it multiple times on one page without changing the way you can initialize and call methods?

Comment: For writing jQuery-Plugins, [jQuery Boilerplate](https://jqueryboilerplate.com/) is a good start and has skeletons for your purposes.

Answer (score 0):

I do this exact same thing myself, and it's very simple once you know how.

Take this example of a simple plugin...

```
$.fn.myPlugin = function() {
    // plugin global vars go here
    // do plugin stuff here
}
```

To modify it to work on multiple instances, you just have to parse `this` when you call it...

```
$.fn.myPlugin = function() {
    $(this).each(function() {
        // plugin global vars go here
        // do plugin stuff here
    });
}
```

That way it will work when you assign the plugin to either a single instance, or a collection of elements.

Then, to call methods on individual elements, you just need to specify the correct one...

```
$("#element1").doMethod(1, 2, 3);
$("#element2").doMethod(4, 5, 6);
```